# How to Delegate Properties to a JPA Entity in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have a JPA entity:

```
@Entity
internal class FooJpaEntity (
  @Id var id: UUID,
  @Column var foo: String, // Never null in DB
)
```

Now we want to hide it from public by wrapping it inside another class:

```
class FooWrapper internal constructor(internal val entity: FooJpaEntity) {
  val id: UUID by Delegate(entity::id)
  val foo: String by Delegate(entity:foo)
}
```

and `Delegate` is:

```
class Delegate<T>(private val delegate: KMutableProperty0<T>) {
  operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = delegate.get()
  operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) { delegate.set(value) }
}
```

The above only supports reading from DB (since nobody has access to the constructor). We need another constructor to support creating new objects to persist into DB:

```
class FooWrapper ... {
  constructor(id: UUID, foo: String): this(FooJpaEntity(id, foo))
  // delegated properties
}
```

Now we can create, edit, persist, and read entities.
One more requirement: I need to do some cleanup on `foo` (let's say trim it, in reality it's more complex though):

```
class FooWrapper internal constructor(internal val entity: FooJpaEntity) {
  constructor(id: UUID, foo: String): this(FooJpaEntity(id, foo))
  val id: UUID by Delegate(entity::id)
  val foo: String
    get() = entity.foo
    set(value) { entity.foo = value.trim() }
}
```

I have two problems with the above:
1. I lost delegation. Probably it's inevitable, since I don't want to put logic in the entity, right?
2. The cleanup logic needs to be duplicated in the constructor as well.

What is the idiomatic way to achieve the above in Kotlin (something more than some auxiliary methods)?
Also if there's any other comment on the above code (about JPA, entities, etc), I'd love to learn. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "Now we want to hide it from public"? Using `internal` modifier you are already making it visible only inside the module where it is defined.

Comment: What I want is to work with persistence layer and entities via the wrapper, not directly. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. I can't think in a better idea than yours. Why you don't want to put logic in the entity? Imho that's the right place to put logic as it is the most intuitive place others developers would look for it. That's also how it would be done in a DDD approach.

Comment: Maybe just add an interface like `CleanableEntity` with a method like `clean` and call it in the init of Delegate?